# Sending an email from a form to my own email, hosted on firebase

Tags: javascript, email, firebase

I have a website that i am developing for a client that needs to have the website hosted on firebase.

There is an contact form on the website that i need to send the contents in an email to the website owners email.

Is there a way to send an email using cloud functions without storing any data or authentication?

Or if there is a better solution that could be used?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at one of the official Firebase samples for Cloud Functions:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation

You can also adapt it in order to use Sengrid, with their library for node.js https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs. Works very well.